# Convergence in distribution implies bounded in probability?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics

I am told this is true (and obvious). I intuitively, it makes sense, but I cannot think of a formal argument for it.

Comment: Yes, it is true. c.f. van der Vaart's asymptotic statistics (theorem 2.4).

Comment: There is no theorem 2.4 in the book

Comment: Theorem 2.4 is on page 8.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2850112/321264